# Triggering scroll events binded with .on()

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

If I bind functions to an event via on:

```
$(el).on('scroll.prlx', function() { ... });
```

I apparently can't trigger the event manually with:

```
$(el).trigger('scroll.prlx');
```

I tried several types of triggering `scroll`. Nothing worked so far.

One solution was to animate the scroll top to 1 and than back to 0 with no speed.
But that still leaves a jump which, is awkward for the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, attach an event handler for scrolling by passing in your function handler like

```
$('#Scrollable').scroll(function(event){
    console.log('I was scrolled');
});
```

Then, trigger like so

```
$('#Scrollable').trigger('scroll');
```

See it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/dgkxgrhk/9/)

Comment: i don't want to scroll a fixed amount of pixel, i want to fire the scroll event i have bound to an object other than $(window); whole other story

Comment: as i said, id used every possible combination of triggering the scroll event. None worked. My momentary solution is moving the div by 1px so the event gets fired trough that. Hacky Macky